# 32-bit boundary in IP header

Tags: networking, network-programming

I am reading about IP headers in TCP illustrated by Richard Stevens. It is mentioned as below

> In IP header options field is present. The options field always ends on a 32-bit boundary. Pad bytes with a value of 0 are added if necessary. This assures that the IP header is always a multiple of 32 bits (as required for the header length field).

I am having difficulty in understanding above statement.

What does author mean by 32-bit boundary?
What does author mean by IP header is always multiple of 32 bits?

Please explain with simple example.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using [image: Picture from nmap.org] as a reference.

One of the fields `IHL (Header Length)` in the TCP Header tells the receiver how many 32 bit chunks make up the header.
Because of the variable length options field at the end it is possible to have a 32bit chunk that is not completely filled.
To make sure that no data is accidentally read as header information, the Header must end at a 32bit multiple which is done using padding.

Answer (score 2):

See the [diagram in the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header#Header).

The IP header ends with something called the "options", which is a variable-length entity. It consists of a sequence of options, encoded as an Option List. Each option requires only a minimum of 16 bits, so it's possible to "un-align" the header by including an odd number of such options. Thus, the need for language to require padding.